# Creating fault tolerant system - Use data file to reload save data?

Tags: java, monitor, fault, fault-tolerance

EDIT - The implementation Language is Java.

I want to make a simple fault tolerant system.

- Object A - This object contains the decision logic for the system.
- Object B - This object will be used control the fault tolerance

My initial ideas are to have object A update object B with the value of variables that are to be saved to a data file. Then object B will create a data file that will be saved to a hard drive of the platform system.

My question is: how would I create a data file using the values of object variables and then retrieve those variables from the data file? when they are called.

I am happy just to write variable values to a notepad file and then recall them from the file

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of detail.  For instance, what programming language you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

For simple use cases where you just want to provide persistence and fault tolerance for in-memory data, you might want to have a look at [Prevayler](http://prevayler.org/).  It's a straightforward library that builds checkpoints (snapshots) and redo journaling on top of serialization, giving you transactional semantics on the cheap.